# Error when using WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, index-maintenance

Okay so I've been condensing files off of some tiny files and moving them onto an FG that I created for these miscellaneous tables. I've been moving these tables by recreating the indexes with the `WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON)` option and it's been working great. However this last time it gave me an error. Here's the script I'm running

```
CREATE Unique CLUSTERED INDEX PK_MyTable 
    ON dbo.MyTable (MyTableID, RowStatus)  
    WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON)  
    ON FG_Misc;
```

When I run this I get the following error message.

> Msg 1902, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>
> Cannot create more than one clustered index on table 'dbo.MyTable'. Drop the existing clustered index PK_MyTable' before creating another.

I don't see any reason why this is throwing this error on this particular table but not any others I've been working on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen when the current primary key is nonclustered, and there is also a clustered index:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
(
    MyTableID integer NOT NULL,
    RowStatus tinyint NOT NULL,
    SomeOtherKey integer,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable]
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (MyTableID, RowStatus),

    CONSTRAINT [CUQ_MyTable]
        UNIQUE CLUSTERED (SomeOtherKey)
);
```

```
CREATE Unique CLUSTERED INDEX PK_MyTable 
    ON dbo.MyTable (MyTableID, RowStatus)  
    WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON);
```

> Msg 1902, Level 16, State 3, Line 14
>   Cannot create more than one clustered index on table 'dbo.MyTable'. Drop the existing clustered index 'CUQ_MyTable' before creating another.

It is valid to change a primary key from nonclustered to clustered using `DROP_EXISTING` syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
(
    MyTableID integer NOT NULL,
    RowStatus tinyint NOT NULL,
    SomeOtherKey integer,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable]
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (MyTableID, RowStatus),
);

CREATE Unique CLUSTERED INDEX PK_MyTable 
    ON dbo.MyTable (MyTableID, RowStatus)  
    WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON);
```